# Android - System settings for accessibility font size are not applied if using androidx

Tags: android, androidx, accessibility

We're trying to make our apps more accessible, and one of the things we're looking at is supporting larger font sizes when configured from the system settings.

We noticed that on Android 7.0 (and probably earlier versions too), the system font sizes are not properly applied within our app. We also noticed that some other apps like gmail were properly handling the font size change, so it was "something" our app was doing wrong. After quite some time investigating we found out that using the androidx library seems to be the cause.

For example, creating a "hello world" new project under Android Studio, you'll see a "use androix artifacts" checkbox:

[image: Android Studio New Project Window]

Then, if you set the accessibility font size to the highest value:
[image: Accessibility font settings]

This will be the result for your app if you **checked** the "androidx" checkbox (not working):
[image: unchanged text size]

This will be the result for your app if you **didn't check** the "androidx" checkbox (working properly):
[image: changed text size]

If you check that box, the produced app binary will not apply system accessibility font size changes properly on Android 7.0, otherwise it will work fine.

Migrating to androidx was a little bit of work and since it's the future (the support library is gradually getting deprecated), going back is not really an option :/

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?
Could that be a bug with the androidx library?

If anyone found a way to keep the androidx library and not have this bug, I would really like to know about it, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Update your implementations, example:
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha01'
You may also need: 
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this doesn't solve the problem: 1.2.0-alpha01 still produces that bug. Also, the android support library is not really an option because it's deprecated now, it won't work long term to keep a maintainable code.

Comment: Ok ... after a search on this link:
(https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat) I chose the June 5, 2019 release. But the IDE (Android Studio) warned to switch to 1.2.0-alpha01. That solved our problem. So please, can you post your androidx implementations? Another thing ... are you using any ttf or xml font? Thank you friend.

Comment: You should create a dedicated answer instead of this comment, updating to 1.2.0-alpha01 fixes the issue.

Comment: Using 1.2.0-alpha02 fixed this problem for me.